# Splitting an array up into chunks of a given size

Tags: javascript

I have written a function which takes two parameters: (1) an Array, (2) size of the chunk.

```
function chunkArrayInGroups(arr, size) {

  var myArray = [];

  for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i += size) {
    myArray.push(arr.slice(i,size));
  }

  return myArray;
}
```

I want to split this array up into chunks of the given size.

```
chunkArrayInGroups(["a", "b", "c", "d"], 2)
```

should return: `[["a", "b"], ["c", "d"]]`.

I get back: `[["a", "b"], []]`

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You misunderstood what the [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) parameters mean. The second one is the index until which (not included) you want to get the subarray. It's not a length.

```
array.slice(from, to); // not array.slice(from, length)
```

```js
function chunkArrayInGroups(arr, size) {
  var myArray = [];
  for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i += size) {
    myArray.push(arr.slice(i, i+size));
  }
  return myArray;
}
console.log(chunkArrayInGroups(["a", "b", "c", "d"], 2));
```