# Chunk a sentence in to phrases with three words

Tags: javascript

How to chunk a string in to 3-word(or less) phrases with brackets at ends?

Following is a sample string

```
This is a sample sentence containing some words with some other meanings.
```

Following is the expected result

```
[This is a sample] [sentence containing some] [words with some] [other meanings.]
```

**I've added mine**

this is what i've tried

```
    this.mod = this.data.replace(/([.?!])\s*(?=[A-Z])/g, "$1|").split("|");
    this.mod.map((sentence) => {
      sentence.split(' ').reduce((acc, cur, idx, arr) => {
        acc + cur
      } ,'')
    })
```

This is also what I've tried & it is not working.

```
    const res = this.mod.map((sentence) => {
      return sentence.split(" ").reduce((acc, cur, idx, arr) => {
        acc + (idx % 3 === 0) ? `][${cur}]` : cur;
      }, "[");
    });
```

Is there any other approach?

Comment: how do you determine a phrase? what have you tried?

Comment: who in their right mind upvoted this post twice?

Comment: Hi. I'm not sure how to determine phrases.

Comment: IS there a way to determine phrases?

Comment: Or may be convert them in to chunks of words of size 3.

Comment: Maybe this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18914629/split-string-into-sentences-in-javascript) can help you.

Comment: That's what I'm doing here.

Comment: to much *maybe*. do you have other examples and outcomes?

Comment: How can I chunk in to phrases?

Comment: Is there a way in vanilla javascript to split a sentence in to meaningful phrases.

Comment: You would need to understand what a meaningful phrase is, which requires some sort of machine learning algorithm. I don't think Javascript is the best choice in this case.

Comment: if this is not possible chunk a sentence in to phrases with three words ??

Comment: Very possible if it's only chunked into 3 words regardless of meaning.

Comment: Can someone suggest a way?

Comment: Yep., for now without any meaning? Is that possible?

Comment: this is possible. maybe you try yourself and edit this question with you approach.

Comment: I've tried. Please check out the update.

Comment: & it is not working.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8495687/split-array-into-chunks, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40682103/splitting-an-array-up-into-chunks-of-a-given-size,  and [.split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)

Comment: Using regex: `'This is a sample sentence containing some words with some other meanings.'.replace(/(\w+ \w+(?: \w+)?)/g,'[$1]')`

Comment: great. Thank you!

Comment: atleaset you helped!

Comment: In all honesty, I was waiting for the question to reopen so I could post my answer. https://jsfiddle.net/abpmyzfL/

Answer (score 1):

Ok here is a simple stab at it:

```
function chunkIt(str) {
  const words = str.split(' ') // split into individual words
  const result = []
  let phrase = []
  for (const word of words) {
    if (phrase.length < 3) {
      phrase.push(word)
    }

    if (phrase.length === 3) {
      result.push(phrase.join(' '))
      phrase = [] 
    }
  }  
  if (phrase.length > 0) {
    result.push(phrase.join(' '))
  }
  return result
}
```